# GridRatingColumn show nothing with null values

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm working on a RadGrid that has all its columns and databinding done at runtime. One of the columns in the grid is a GridRatingColumn. It works, but I'd like to be able to differentiate between items with a value of 0 and items with no value (Null). Currently, the GridRatingColumn shows a rating of 0 for Null values.

Is there a way to have a GridRatingColumn be empty (no stars) with a Null value and display blank stars with a value of 0?

Code:

```
Dim colScore As GridRatingColumn = New GridRatingColumn
_grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(colScore)
colScore.DataField = "score"
colScore.HeaderText = "Score"
colScore.UniqueName = "colScore"
colScore.ItemCount = 5
colScore.Precision = RatingPrecision.Half
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to hide controls corresponding to null ratings in your grid's RowDataBound event.

According to Telerik documentation (more details can be found here [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/gridratingcolumn/defaultvb.aspx)) you can manually retrieve the control like this:

> The ID of the rating control in each column cell is
>   **Rating_[ColumnUniqueName]**, where **[ColumnUniqueName]** is the UniqueName
>   of the **GridRatingColumn** instance.